# Are WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy or WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy() calling CFNetwork.GetDefaultProxy () in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to sign out a reference to the MonoTouch library and all that is used is:

```
IWebProxy oDefaultProxy =  CFNetwork.GetDefaultProxy ();
```

In .NET, there's also `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` and `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy(`). Is either one of these resolving `CFNetwork.GetDefaultProxy ()` on iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you mean by *sign out a reference*. However you have the Mono source code included with your MonoTouch installation (and can even set breakpoints inside it).

Also since Mono is open source github also have an *almost* identical copy so you can see what 
[`DefaultWebProxy`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2-10/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs#L215) and [`GetSystemWebProxy`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2-10/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs#L345) do, which is for OSX (and iOS) calling [`CFNetwork.GetDefaultProxy`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2-10/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs#L348).

Comment: I have a library that i would like to use on other platforms (Windows) but it references MonoTouch.CoreFoundation only because of the usage of CFNetwork. That's why I was looking for a compatible replacement.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here: what references CoreFoundation, your library or Mono ?

If you're talking about Mono's `System.dll`, don't worry, the P/Invokes in [MacProxy.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/MacProxy.cs) are only invoked if you're on a Mac, so these shouldn't cause problems on other platforms.

If you need to get the system web proxy somewhere lese, look at [WebProxy.GetSystemWebProxy](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs) for an example, though you could also just simply call that method.